# Get the filename of which the function is inside in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

Lets say we have 2 Files
FileA.js:

```
function foo(){
    return;
}
```

FileB.js:

```
const filea = require("FileA.js");
console.log( GetFunctionFileName( filea.foo ));
```

How can I make it so that `console.log( GetFunctionFileName( filea.foo ));` Prints `FileA.js`?

Comment: you want exactly the string `"FileA.js"` to print? but, you know `filea.foo` comes from `FileA.js` ... since you required it from there ... what is the point? though, as it stands, `filea.foo` will be undefined, since fileA.js doesn't export a single thing

Comment: This feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)